# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'a.jpg'

Tags: python

I want to open a random image if the number is even, but it says file not found? Even if that file with that exact name exists.

```
import random
import os
himg = r'C:\Users\Vl\Desktop\aaaa\himg'
files = os.listdir(himg)
d = random.choice(files)
rng1 = (random.randint(0, 10))
if (rng1 % 2) == 0:
os.startfile(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add new backslash in front of current backslash.
os.startfile require file directory + file name (if your script not in  the same directory with the files)

```
import random
import os
himg = 'C:\\Users\\Vl\\Desktop\\aaaa\\himg\\'
files = os.listdir(himg)
d = random.choice(files)
rng1 = (random.randint(0, 10))
if (rng1 % 2) == 0:
  os.startfile(himg + d)
```